# How to ArrayJoin multiple strings into single SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have many (over few thousands) SQL strings ie like this:

```
update tw__Tow set tw_SeAu = '0' where tw_Symbol = '0110';
update tw__Tow set tw_SeAu = '5' where tw_Symbol = '0125';
update tw__Tow set tw_SeAu = '1' where tw_Symbol = '253';
```

Instead of sending each statement into SQL database separately I need to join all of them into one single query using ArrayJoin but I don't how to do this.

My friend advised me to ArrayJoin all the strings, but I'd be glad with any solution.

Thank You in advance
Martin

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? (Two different products, with somewhat different SQL...)

Comment: ArrayJoin is not a SQL function.

Comment: Can you use a single transaction? As @jarlh said, depends on the SQL server that you use...

Comment: SQL-server-2008, I'm using Excel to send them into SQL database

Answer (score 0):

Try `case`

```
 UPDATE tw__Tow 
        SET tw_SeAu = CASE
            WHEN tw_Symbol = '0110' THEN 0
            WHEN tw_Symbol ='0125' THEN 5
            WHEN tw_Symbol ='253' THEN 1
        END
  WHERE tw_Symbol in ('0110','0110','253')
```

Comment: That would work but I can't change the strings. It would take me forever to rebuild them like this. I need to find a way to join all the strings into one query without changing them.